# jquery validate avoid add errorClass to input

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The `validate` plugin on error also adds errorClass to input field. How to avoid this?

```
var validator = $("#contacts_form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();  //Must be called here,
        },
        errorElement: "p",
        errorClass : 'form-item-validation',
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            website: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            onchange: true
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter your firstname",
            email: {
                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You could set it to an empty string, however it's worth noting that the same class is applied to the form controls as it is to the `label` elements. Therefore if you need them to be different, that's not possible. I'm not sure why you'd need to avoid the class on the form elements anyway. Just amend the CSS rules if it's a UI issues

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well, errorClass : 'form-item-validation' has styles and thats breaks all, I only need add error class to the message container but not to the input

Comment: `'form-item-validation' has styles and thats breaks all` in that case just change the CSS as you need.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its not a case to change css, I didn't create them and I don't know who will add or replace them

Comment: I presume `onchange` is not one of your field names?  Please note that only field names followed by their methods go inside of the `rules` object, so basically, `onchange: true` makes absolutely no sense inside there.  Secondly, `onchange` is not even an option for this plugin:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=onchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is add to the settings

```
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            this.defaultShowErrors();
            $('input').removeClass('form-item-validation');
        },
```

Comment: Actually, `highlight` and `unhighlight` are the two options you should use for adding and removing classes during validation.

Comment: showErrors does it too actually or there are some hidden stones?

Comment: Look at the source code.  The two I mentioned already are the methods for reliably adding/removing classes at the proper validation events.